# How to use own word embedding with pre-trained embedding like word2vec in Keras

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, word-embedding

I have a co-occurrence matrix stored in a CSV file which contains the relationship between words and emojis like this:

```
word emo1 emo2 emo3
w1   0.5   0.3  0.2
w2   0.8   0    0
w3   0.2   0.5  0.2
```

This co-occurrence matrix is huge which has `1584755` rows and `621` columns. I have a `Sequential() LSTM` model in `Keras` where I use pre-trained (word2vec) word-embedding. Now I would like to use the co-occurrence matrix as another embedding layer. How can I do that? My current code is something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embeddings_dim, input_length=max_sent_len, weights=[embedding_weights]))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample_length=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=pool_length))
model.add(LSTM(embeddings_dim))
model.add(Dense(reg_dimensions))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit( train_sequences , train_labels , nb_epoch=30, batch_size=16)
```

Also, if the co-occurrence matrix is sparse then what would be the best way to use it in the embedding layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Embedding` layer and set your own weight matrix like this:

```
Embedding(n_in, n_out, trainable=False, weights=[weights])
```

If I understood you correctly `weights` will be your co-occurrence matrix, `n_in` the number of rows and `n_out` the number of columns.

You can find some more information and examples in [this](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) blog post.

Comment: Ok thanks but the co-occurrence matrix is stored in a csv file. How can I link the file to the embedding? The blog post uses test and train data in embedding but my test and train data are different than the matrix.

Comment: @AbuShoeb Then you have to load the `csv` in your code, either using `pandas` or `numpy`. There is no way to 'link' the file to the weights directly.